# Blank page in Wordpress after write a comment

Tags: php, wordpress

I never see this problem before in Wordpress.

I construct custom template but when I insert the code

```
comments_template();
```

And submit any comment, the result is a blank page. If I active the WP_debug in my wp_config like this

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
```

The error (is a warning) is only:

```
    [18-Dec-2014 15:57:15] PHP Notice:  wp_enqueue_script se llamó <strong>incorrectamente</strong>. Los scripts y estilos no se deberían registrar o enganchar hasta que se carguen los ganchos  y  Por favor, mira <a href="http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress">Debugging in WordPress</a> para más información. (Este mensaje se añadió en la versión 3.3.) in /home/desarrollo/www/mywebsite/www/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3370
    [18-Dec-2014 15:57:15] PHP Stack trace:
    [18-Dec-2014 15:57:15] PHP   1. {main}() /home/desarrollo/www/mywebsite/www/index.php:0
    [18-Dec-2014 15:57:15] PHP   2. require() /home/desarrollo/www/mywebsite/www/index.php:17
    [18-Dec-2014 15:57:15] PHP   3. require_once() /home/desarrollo/www/mywebsite/www/wp-blog-header.php:12
    [18-Dec-2014 15:57:15] PHP   4. require_once() /home/desarrollo/www/mywebsite/www/wp-load.php:29
    [18-Dec-2014 15:57:15] PHP   5. require_once() /home/desarrollo/www/mywebsite/www/wp-config.php:82
    [18-Dec-2014 15:57:15] PHP   6. include() /home/desarrollo/www/mywebsite/www/wp-settings.php:329
    [18-Dec-2014 15:57:15] PHP   7. wp_enqueue_script() /home/desarrollo/www/mywebsite/www/wp-content/themes/mywebsite/functions.php:262
    [18-Dec-2014 15:57:15] PHP   8. _doing_it_wrong() /home/desarrollo/www/mywebsite/www/wp-includes/functions.wp-scripts.php:200
    [18-Dec-2014 15:57:15] PHP   9. trigger_error() /home/desarrollo/www/mywebsite/www/wp-includes/functions.php:3370
```

What can be the problem? I construct my functions.php like other sites who have enabled the comments and works well.

Edit:

I put my code (to enqueque script, I've this only for jQuery). I always use this method and works in others websites.

```
add_action('init', 'my_init_method');
/* Mi jQuery */
function my_init_method() {
    if (!is_admin()){
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_register_script( 'jquery', '/wp-content/themes/myTheme/js/jquery-1.11.1.js');
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you have on line 3370 of functions.php

Comment: Can you translate the error for us, since this is an English website?

Comment: This is somthing strange because my functions.php (who have a include with other file) only have 1556 lines with functions lines and my other php file @MarcoMura

Comment: Check this: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2011/12/12/use-wp_enqueue_scripts-not-wp_print_styles-to-enqueue-scripts-and-styles-for-the-frontend/

Comment: For others: the error is I think: `wp enqueue script was called incorrectly scripts and styles should not be registered`

Comment: I put my function code in the question @lolka_bolka ...I've this in others websites and works